# Azure web job: Can't bind Queue to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues

I've created a web job in Azure. This web job gets triggered by my web api. This web job also is set to run "continuously". However, from the moment I start the web job, I receive this error message (seen in the logs):

> Can't bind Queue to type 'System.String'

And my web job tries to restart, and gets the same error message again, and again.

I've tried to do some research on this error message, but I'm not finding much of anything. Has anyone ever seen this error before? Here is my code in the functions.cs file:

```
namespace DownloadProcessor
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([Queue("ringclonedownloadprocessorqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine("Processing" + message);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems very straightforward. Also, here is my function in my Program.cs file:

```
namespace DownloadProcessor
{
    // To learn more about Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320976
    class Program
    {
        // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
        // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
        static void Main()
        {
            var host = new JobHost();
            // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
    }
}
```

It all seems very straightforward, and I have created other similar web jobs exactly like this. Has anyone ever seen this error message before? Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when using functions in Node.js environment. In my case, it was due to the fact I forgot to specify the `"direction": "out"` for the output binding in `function.json` file

Comment: Such an obvious mistake can be such a hassle. The error log makes this not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into this issue, I found out what was going on (in my case). My problem was with this line:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([Queue("ringclonedownloadprocessorqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
```

This web job was **not** a continuous job when I first created it. And when Visual Studio created the code template, it used `[Queue("ringclonedownloadprocessorqueue")] string message` as the default parameter type. I recently changed the job to a continuous job, and a continuous job uses a slightly different param type (`QueueTrigger` instead of `Queue`). But when I changed the job to continuous, Visual Studio did not change the param type accordingly. I needed to go in and manually update the param type. Changing the function to this did the trick:

```
namespace DownloadProcessor
{
    public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("ringclonedownloadprocessorqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine("Processing" + message);
        }
    }
}
```